# Link within link issue: Placing a link inside a clickable element

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML table which contains group rows that allow their child rows to be expanded and collapsed via jQuery when clicked. Each group row contains a single column that spans across all of the table's columns. Within this column is a link that opens a new window.

The problem occurs when clicking the new window link. Not only does the new window open, but clicking the link causes the group row's onclick event to fire which toggles the group of rows. Any ideas on how I can prevent the toggle when the new window link is clicked while allowing toggle when the row is clicked anywhere else?

```
<tr class="groupRow" onclick="toggleChildRows()">  
    <td colspan="@tableColumnCount">
        <a href="@newWindowPath">New Window</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: In my opinion, Bad design. Can you clarify when it should toggle and new window should open?

Comment: Its a common issue and you can use [event.stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to limit the event to its element only

Comment: @Satpal Haven't you ever used twitter? Most modern web applications have a use case for this. You want to be able click on a list item, for example, to open a conversation thread, while also being able to click "like" or "share" without triggering the outside link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are better ways to make this, but you can stop the propagation (bubbling) of the link and it will work:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="alert('yeah');">
  <a href="@newWindowPath">New Window</a>
  <div>click this</div>
</div>
```